# heading element Overflow on Dynamic Width - display: block and min-height/width on contained container div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

Specifically the vertical text outlined in white.

[image]

I am able to do this and make it dynamic (so there is no overlap between each of the words "fale" "que" "nem" "um" "gringo"), but it requires that I created a containing div for each of the headers, like so,

```
<div id="fale_textbox_0">
    <div class="highlight0a" id="Fale">
       <h1 class="fale_heading">Fale</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="highlight0a" id="que">
        <h1 class="fale_heading">que</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="highlight0a" id="nem">
       <h1 class="fale_heading">nem</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="highlight0a" id="um">
       <h1 class="fale_heading">um</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that it's because  is a block-type element. Why, then does it not work if I do

```
<div id="fale_text_container">
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="fale">Fale</h1>
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="que">que</h1>
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="nem">nem</h1>
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="um">um</h1>
    <div id="fale_textbox_2">
        <h1 class id="fale_heading_2">Rápido</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="fale_textbox_3">
        <h2 id="fale_subheading_2">Sem Sotaque</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="fale_textbox_1">
        <h2 id="fale_subheading_1">GRINGO</h2>
    </div>
```

Then set the container to `display: block` with `min-width` and `max-width` established.  Like so:

```
  #fale_container {
          width: 100%;
          float: left;
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 0;
          background-color: black;
          height: auto;
          min-height: 300px;
          position: relative; }

    #fale_container_padding {
          position: relative;
          height: 20%; }

    #fale_text_container {
          position: relative; }

    .fale_heading {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          width: 13.32756%;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 0.00666%;
          margin-left: 13.33422%;
          color: black;
          font-size: 3.5em;
          clear: right; }

    #fale, #que, #nem, #um {
          z-index: 10; }

    #fale {
          margin-top: -18%; }

    #fale:after {
          content: '';
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
          width: 87%;
          height: 100%;
          left: 8%; }

    #que {
          margin-top: -9.5%; }

    #que:after {
          content: '';
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #fff;
          height: 100%;
          width: 73%;
          left: 8%; }

    #nem {
          margin-top: -1%; }

    #nem:after {
      content: '';
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #fff;
          height: 100%;
          width: 82%;
          left: 8%; }

    #um {
          margin-top: 7%; }

    #um:after {
          content: '';
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #fff;
          height: 100%;
          width: 89%;
          left: 8%; }
```

When I do it like this there's overlap. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ya6zfLf/)

Block alone doesn't work. Neither does `block` and `min-width` and `min-height.` Neither does `min-width` and `min-height` without `block.` Is it because the container is set to `position:relative` inside of a `<div>` that's height is set to `auto?`

Why don't `Block` nor `min` properties work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ya6zfLf/1/

**HTML**

You need to wrap all the floating elements into a container and give `position: absolute;` to that. (Instead of to individual headings) This way each of your headings can be positioned relatively and maintain their heights perfectly.

```
<div class="white-strips-container">
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="fale">Fale</h1>
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="que">que</h1>
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="nem">nem</h1>
    <h1 class="fale_heading" id="um">um</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

For the new wrapper class

```
.white-strips-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}
```

For the headings

```
.fale_heading {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 0.00666%;
  margin-left: 13.33422%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  height: 50px;
  clear: right; 
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```